# glsl refraction getting mapped upside down

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am implementing refraction in glsl. I am using the refract function provided in frag shader to get the desired effect. But the refraction I am getting, its upside down. I think this is wrong.. any idea why is it so?

This is what I do in vertex shader:

```
vec3 worldView = normalize(vec3(WorldCameraPosition-worldPos));
refractor = refract(-worldView, worldNorm, Eta); // eta = 0.66;
```

and then frag shader I do:

```
vec4 refractColor = textureCube(cubeMap, refractor);
```

[http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~duttas/Images_5542/Capture.PNG http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~duttas/Images_5542/Capture.PNG](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~duttas/Images_5542/Capture.PNG)

Comment: Screenshots would help. Or links to screenshots, if you don't have enough rep to include images.

Comment: http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~duttas/Images_5542/RT_rendering.html

the very last image of the page. Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're talking about the refractions on those spheres, I'm pretty sure what you've got is the correct result, it's supposed to be upside down. Due to the way the light refracts off the spherical surface the image you see in the sphere is reversed:

[image: https://summerexplorations.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/marbles2.jpg?w=584]

Real world example:

[image: http://www.physicscentral.com/explore/pictures/images/crystal-ball_2.jpg]
<sub>(source: [physicscentral.com](http://www.physicscentral.com/explore/pictures/images/crystal-ball_2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: GREAT JOB. Owner of that question probably forgot that its not REFLECTION (of something that is behind) but refraction (of something that is behind). And nice pick :P +1

Comment: Yep, that seems right. Bring your refraction index (eta) closer to 1 to get less upsidedownness, if that's what you want.